# How to get colored output from magic commands such as `!grep` when using IPython as the shell?

Tags: bash, shell, ipython, ipython-magic

In the bash shell, using for example `grep <pattern> <file>` would result in every line containing the pattern to be returned and the pattern to be highlighted in red bold font in each of these lines. However, when I use `!grep` from the IPython shell, the pattern is not highlighted in the returned lines.

Similarly, from within the IPython shell, `!ls` does not produce colored or bold output, while `ls` does. Is there any way to enable highlighting in the output from magic commands in the IPython shell?

I am Ubuntu 15.04, using IPython 3.2.0.

Comment: Read `man grep`, search for `color`.

Comment: Try `grep --color=always` and `ls --color=always`.  These should work for the `grep` and `ls` from gnu coreutils.

Comment: ah, I thought color was the default for `grep`, I didn't realize there was an alias set up automatically by Ubuntu in my `.bashrc`. So is there any way I can get IPython to respect my aliases, instead of passing the commands without any parameters?

Comment: I found [this](http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-make-IPython-import-the-aliases-defined-in-my-bash-profile-upon-startup), but maybe there is a simpler way?

Comment: [Many people](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/bash-kernel-colors-for-stdout/6560/2) are wondering how to do this.